# Should I use full URLs or paths from the root of the application on my site?

Tags: php, session, url, authentication

I tried to originally use full paths to the various pages on my site because it was better for the SEO of my site, and thus was a business-driven requirement.

But now a bug has been discovered that occurs when users log in, and the full path causes the session to think they are not logged in.  So they have to log in again for the auth mechanism to finally realize they are logged in.

Has anyone ever seen that before? What is a good solution?  Ideally I'd need to keep my full url paths.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: i don't really see how the paths connect with the authentication process :/ Can you provide some more detail on the auth mechanism ?

Comment: Do you mean "full path with hostname"? Could there be a "comehike.com" versus "www.comehike.com" issue with your paths and cookies?

Comment: Yes that is what I am suspecting as well.  The www. issue - how is this usually handled?

Comment: Try explicitly setting the domain for your cookies to ".comehike.com", then they should be sent to both comehike.com and www.comehike.com.

Comment: the domains name should be enough.

Comment: The best thing to do is to force all access to comehike.com/foo to redirect to www.comehike.com/foo (or vice versa). Having a canonical URL is better for SEO, your in-bound links aren't diluted between the two different URLs for foo.